# How to recognize business log from Spring application log and tag them in Logger.info()?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback, slf4j

I'm using Spring Boot and Logback to record my log.

The requirement is that I want to recognize business log from Spring application log and tag them in Logger.info().

For example:

In one of my Foo.service

```
LOGGER.info("this is my business log, I want to tag it")
```

I want to differentiate it from the application system log and the Middleware log. However, I can not figure out a method to judge the log is written by me(Business logic programmer) or the application system log.

Comment: If you have found a solution among the given answers, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, please clarify the above question so that it can be better answered to suit the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach is that each Logger object that you're using has a name. Most commonly, there's one Logger object per class, and you give it a name which is the same as the class that it's in. If your business logic is in a particular package, those loggers all have the same prefix, and you can set whatever logging configuration you want, directing those logs to a separate file or whatever it is that you're trying to do.

If you are looking for something more complicated than that, the SLF4J/Logback approach would be to [use Markers](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#fatal):

```
Marker businessNotification = MarkerFactory.getMarker("BUSINESS_NOTIFICATION");
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("aLogger");
//…
logger.info(businessNotification, "this is my business log")
```

You can then use %marker in Logback's [PatternLayout](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ClassicPatternLayout), or do more sophisticated [filtering](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) by marker.

Comment: Thank for your advice! Seems Using a common filter or prefix is a better idea. Using %marker in PatternLayout may add extra logging codes to business logic codes.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid writing duplicate code (such as adding a prefix or marker to each message), you can create your own simple wrapper class:

```
public class BusinessLogger {
    private final Logger logger; // initialize in constructor, can even add a getter if needed

    public void info(String msg) {
        logger.info("[BUSINESS] " + msg);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// class member, can even be static
BusinessLogger logger = new BusinessLogger(LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()));

// in a method
logger.info("this is my business log")
```

Output:

```
[2019-02-13 13:41:21.009] [INFO] 12540 [Test worker] : [BUSINESS] this is my business log
```

This will work well if you want all of your logs to be business logs anyway. If you must still use the original logger, you can do `logger.getLogger().info("non-business info");`, giving:

```
[2019-02-13 13:41:22.414] [INFO] 12540 [Test worker] : non-business info
```

Comment: Marker are natively handled by logback and log4j; the OP clearly stated they already use logback.

Comment: @Saucistophe You can modify the above `info` method to use a marker instead of the string prefix, either way the result is the same. **The main point** of my post is writing a custom wrapper class instead of repeating `logger.info(aMarkerVariable, "message")` for each log case. Developers can and *will* forget to use the two-parameter method in some cases and *will* occasionally write `logger.info("message")` by accident. Better to not rely on that. If you wish, you may suggest what I should improve in my answer or edit it yourself :)

Comment: Ooh ok I get it. My bad.